# Am I using too many elseif statements? Is there a better way of performing large conditionals like this?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a fairly large if/elseif/else conditional and I'm wondering if this could possibly be the best way of doing this, or if there's a better way?

```
if (($site == '1') && ($theAction == 'subscribe')) {
    $url = "https://test1.com/?na=ajaxsub";
} elseif (($site == '2') && ($theAction == 'subscribe')) {
    $url = "https://test2.com/?na=ajaxsub";
} elseif (($site == '3') && ($theAction == 'subscribe')) {
    $url = "https://test3.com/?na=ajaxsub";
} elseif (($site == '4') && ($theAction == 'subscribe')) {
    $url = "https://test4.com/?na=ajaxsub";
} elseif (($theAction == 'unsubscribe') && ($site == '1' | '2' | '3' | '4')) {
    $url = "https://test5.com/unsubscribe.php";
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: there are other ways, but let me just point out this is wrong `$site == '1' | '2' | '3' | '4'` php does not work like that, you could do `.. && in_array($site,array(1,2,3,4)) ..`

Comment: you could also use the $site varaible as part of the url to reduce this somewhat, but it may just be an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it seems as though you want to redirect to the same page *whenever* a user is trying to unsubscribe, regardless of what `$site` is, so you can take this part completely out of the equation.

From here, I would recommend making an associative array that maps each `$site` index to their corresponding site. You can then simply set `$url` based on the index of this new assictaive array as follows:

```
$site = 1; // Set the site as an integer
$theAction = 'subscribe'; // As long as it is not 'unsubscribe' the `else` will trigger

$mappings = array("1"=>"https://test1.com/?na=ajaxsub", 
                  "2"=>"https://test2.com/?na=ajaxsub", 
                  "3"=>"https://test3.com/?na=ajaxsub", 
                  "4"=>"https://test4.com/?na=ajaxsub");

if ($theAction == 'unsubscribe') {
  $url = "https://test5.com/unsubscribe.php";
}
else {
  $url = $mappings[$site];
}

echo $url; // https://test1.com/?na=ajaxsub
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/9Nfb5)**.

And you can even shrink down the conditional using a ternary, if you so desire:

```
$theAction == 'unsubscribe' ? $url = "https://test5.com/unsubscribe.php" : $url = $mappings[$site];
```

Which can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/URnqj)**.

Comment: you should probably check the URL in the unsub section like the OP does